# Minecraft Bedrock Render Distance limited at 16 chunks

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play minecraft bedrock edition

This question, if it is closed due to duplicate the duplicate anwser is for JAVA, not bedrock.

My render distance in the settings maxes out at 16 chunks, but I have seen images of it being able to go higher.

How do I set the render distance in minecraft BE past 16 chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The "render distance" depends on the graphics capability of your computer.** For example, my gaming PC can go up to 48 chunks, while my less powerful computer (with identical settings) can only go up to 16 chunks. This same rule applies to mobile devices as well.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with RAM. Because I have a gaming PC with 1/4 the RAM.

Comment: @Abraham What exactly do you mean by "1/4" the RAM?

Comment: Nevermind on that.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason that does not happen to me, I get a consistent 64 render distance to the max on any version and yes it does lag when you put it that high. So I think what they are doing is that they are decreasing it for some devices that cannot handle it because it will lag.

Comment: This adds nothing helpful to the other answer. Please read the existing answers before answering yourself.